# Can I set a condition in an Engagement Plan with no rule so it always evaluates to 'True'?

Tags: engagement-plans

[image]

We are using Sitecore version 8.2.5.  I wanted to set my condition to have no rules so it basically falls through after a wait period in the first condition, executes the triggers then moves to the next step.  Right now my user is hung in the first state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

There is present /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/System/True rule. It always return true.